# Tables not creating locally but creating fine on the Development server

Tags: mysql, setup-script, setup

I had installed one extension locally which is not able to create tables which are their in that extension sql setup file.but if i upload same extension on the development server the extension creates the tables and works fine.

their is no record for this module in the core_resource table.i checked this

i get the following error

`a:5:{i:0;s:101:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project_client.tablename' doesn't exist";i:1;s:5262:"#0 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array`)

Please Help me.

Comment: Standard question, but I have to ask...did you clear the cache on local?

Comment: yes i did cleared caches also.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing module's record from `core_resource` table. This will trigger all setup scripts once again.

Comment: their is no record for this module in the core_resource table.i checked this.

Comment: The record is not based on the table name but your module alias.